# Assign max values to both connected shapes - opencv

Tags: python, opencv, tracking, motion

I have a motion tracking project and achieved a detection stage as of now. For tracking,  im thinking to assign old blob (labelled blobs) value to overlapped ones on next frame (get new place of objects).

I highly prefer opencv functions for speed matters. Is it going to be around morphological functions?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with morphology. You can do this manually super easy just indexing the image with the masks you have. Say you have the connected component labeling of the current frame and previous frame. For each label in the current frame, create a mask for that label, and then mask the previous frame's labeled image with that mask. That should show you the prior label (and probably some zeros) so you can just take the max over that maxed region, and assign it back to the current labeled image at the positions you already have a mask for.

Comment: Note you'll need to get a little creative here with assigning unique values---you'll want to make sure any new component that comes up that doesn't overlap with something else, it may keep its label but that might conflict with the labels in the previous frame, so for each new component that doesn't overlap make sure you reassign it a new label that wasn't in the previous frame.

Comment: Yes, this is an approach. Please consider factor since it is going to be a video processing. Lets go a step back,  how connected components at opencv labelling work? What about hacking it? So it's get updated instead of recalculated?

Comment: Connected components is a pretty quick operation in OpenCV, it's extremely optimized to the point of being [absolutely unreadable](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/db88cd1b255ddf21034f18f6488b0b599c59bf9a/modules/imgproc/src/connectedcomponents.cpp) code, but works great nonetheless. You should be able to run this at 30 FPS on a regular computer for a regularly sized video. Are you working with something more particular? If so, you should add it to your question as right now it's super broad.